# How to get Container name for PFX key?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cryptography, pfx, assembly-signing

Some time ago I installed my PFX key into Container using command like this:

```
sn -i mykey.pfx VS_XXX
```

but two months later I forgot the Container name (VS_XXX), so my question is: 
How to get than name back? I know key name, I have this key, I know the key pass phrase.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640650/calculating-vs-key-container-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the [Keypal](https://www.jensign.com/dotnet/keypal/index.html) utility and double click it, you will find all the names of the key containers. You can choose between user profile and machine profile.

Alternatively, enumerate the certificate store to find the certificate of interest via its subject and then you can use `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` to get the value for `PCERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID`. This approach requires the use of Microsoft's cryptoAPI

Comment: The utility page is gone.

Comment: Updated the link, it's now a .NET program

Answer (score 0):

you could just re-install the key with a new container name:

```
sn -i mykey.pfx VS_ABAB1234ABAB1234
```

Comment: As far as I know, this fails with "Failed to install key pair -- Object already exists." if you already have the key installed with the different container.

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2021: Found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59999581/9862613

You can get the container name using [SnInstallPfx](https://github.com/honzajscz/SnInstallPfx) tool:

```
SnInstallPfx.exe yourKey.pfx
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30537858)

Comment: @Jamjitul thanks. I've added usage example now