# How to get information about key container through certificate public key in CryptoAPI?

Tags: c++, cryptoapi

In C# I can do this by using

```
public static CspKeyContainerInfo GetKeyConatinerInformation(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
   if (certificate == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");

   ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm key = certificate.PublicKey.Key as ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm;
      if (key == null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown key type");

   return key.CspKeyContainerInfo;
}
```

I want to know how can i get this by using C++ and lib CryptoAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.idrix.fr/Root/Samples/pfx_parse.cpp) is a program written by Mounir IDRASSI. This will provide you with the information you are looking for.

Also look for the related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443642/how-to-get-container-name-for-pfx-key/6446601#6446601).